# CPU Usage in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm fairly new to Xcode and I was wondering what the CPU bars represent when you run your iOS app in the simulator.

Do the CPU bars represent how much processing power the simulator is using on my Mac or does it represent how much it would use if it would run on the latest iOS device?

Comment: Obvious to someone who has programming experience, but not to someone who is just getting their feet wet with programming and using iOS as their first platform, as I suspect our friend here may be.

Comment: Just a personal opinion: asking a more basic question shouldn't be grounds for down voting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is how much CPU it is using on the Mac. The simulator does not reflect in any way the performance of a device. You will need to debug on a device to get device performance data.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DebugYourApp/DebugYourApp.html)